# Disable multiple sort in Django Admin >= 1.4

Tags: django, sorting, django-admin, admin

I am using Django Non Rel on App Engine and it is a problem the feature of sort by multiple columns in Django Admin, because I need a lot of indexes.
I would like to recreate the behavior in Django 1.3, where you can sort only by a column when you click it.

I tried googling and everything, but I couldn't find how.

Answer (score 1):

There's no "proper" way to do this (in 1.4, not sure about later versions)

However, it turned out to be quite simple to disable in code.

Edit the `result_headers` function in `django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py`

At line 149, insert the following lines (just before the `yield` statement):

```
o_list_primary = [make_qs_param(new_order_type, i)]
o_list_toggle = [make_qs_param(new_order_type, i)]
```

---

Why is it desirable to disable multiple sort functionality?

When using django-nonrel (e.g. on google app engine) each unique combination of sort orders requires its own index. For a list with 5 sortable columns, this requires more than the maximum permitted number of indexes per entity (which is currently 200)

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about reverting this change: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11868 . I don't understand what you mean by "I need a lot of indexes," so I don't understand why you would want to remove this functionality. In Django >1.4, you still "sort by only one column when you click it" -- the difference is if you then click on a second column, that becomes the secondary sorting for when elements of the first column are identical.

Anyway, if for some reason you want to revert this functionality, you could try adding an [old version](https://github.com/django/django/tree/stable/1.3.x/django/contrib/admin) of the django/contrib/admin directory to your project folder, and then it will use the old admin.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your "change_list.html" file, inside the {% block object-tools %}

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('a[href^="?o="]').each(function(){this.href=this.href.replace(/\..*/,'')});
}
</script>
```

If you do not have jQuery loaded, you'll need to include it. I recommend including in "base_site.html"